# How resolve error with npm run dev (laravel5.4)

Tags: node.js, laravel

When i do npm run dev, 
take that(2018-11-03T17_07_54_524Z-debug.log):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/peter/laraveltraine/projects/blog/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /home/peter/laraveltraine/projects/blog
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
12 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
13 verbose pkgid @
14 verbose cwd /home/peter/laraveltraine/projects/blog
15 verbose Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
16 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
17 verbose node v8.12.0
18 verbose npm  v6.4.1
19 error file sh
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error @ dev: `node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the @ dev script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I try to reinstall & change rules, it's not work for me.

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

I also changed the path from:
node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js
to

node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js

It's not help

Comment: sudo npm* not work

Comment: Any reason why you wrote the scripts that way? The [original Laravel 5.4 package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.4/package.json) has them as e.g. `"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",` the cross-env js you're calling there is not necessarily the node executable

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the node_modules directory, that worked for me many times.
Or maybe if you have Homestead, try the command inside and outside the virtual machine. But always better remove the directory and install again.